# Can Outlook Device Policy monitor anything outside of the app?

Tags: security, outlook, device-administrator

In order to get emails for work on my phone I need to enable this feature. My worry is that this will allow my employer to monitor personal things on my phone such as my internet  search history or messages. This is what needs to be enabled.

[image]

Comment: Related [Are device administrator permissions a security risk?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/201665/131553)

Answer (score 1):

`Monitor Screen Unlock attempts` is not nefarious.  Many apps do this.  It is a way to stop people getting to your data by wiping the phone when this happens.

I have mine setup (not using Outlook, a different app) to take a photo after 3 unsuccessful attempts and email it to me.

In your case once you enable Outlook Device Policy monitor, the setup will have what measure you want to take when this happens - Locking up the phone, wiping all data etc.

This is not to say, that there aren't other features that may spy on you.

I would suggest that you activate it, look through the warnings and setup,  Then deactivate if you are unhappy.

Comment: When I press activate it just starts to allow me to see my email. No other warnings or setup.